# Pandas Running Subtotal with Filtering - Apply and Lambda?

Tags: python, pandas, split-apply-combine

I'm trying to build something, that for each record in a pandas database, will show the total for a given column and also show the total for certain records in a given column that occur prior to the date of that record.

**Note that the comparison should be STARTDATE of current record compared to ENDDATE of all records** (only profit on periods that end before the current period should count)

I needed to clarify this because Diego Amicabile came up with a really spiffy answer below that unfortunately doesn't get me where I need to be (I originally posted the question with only a report date field)

[image]

So in this dataframe, I would want two columns on the end.  Total Profit (or sumall) and company profit (or sumco)

Sumall, would be 0 for the first record, -500 for the second record (all dates before 2017-01-01) 300 for the 3rd record (-500+800), etc

Sumco would be 0 until we got to the second IBM record, which would be -500 .  It remains -500 on the 3rd IBM record because the end time on the second record (2017-03-03) is after the start time on the 3rd record.

It should look as follows:

[image]
Code follows.. I am doing something wrong, but can't figure out what it is

```
import io
import pandas as pd

text = """CO         SECTOR    PROFIT   STARTMVYEAR TOTALPROFIT STARTDATE ENDDATE
IBM         TECHNOLOGY  -500    2500        500         2017-01-01 2017-01-01
APPLE       TECHNOLOGY   800    4000        300         2017-01-02 2017-01-03
GM          INDUSTRIAL   250    1000          0         2017-02-01 2017-02-03
IBM    INDUSTRIAL   600    3000        100         2017-03-01 2017-03-03
IBM    INDUSTRIAL   600    35000        100         2017-03-02 2017-06-01"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[0])

df['sumall'] = df.apply(lambda y:  df[df['ENDDATE'] < y['STARTDATE'] ].PROFIT.sum())
df['sumco'] = df.apply(lambda y:  df[(df['ENDDATE'] < y['STARTDATE'] )& (df.co==y.co)].PROFIT.sum())
```

Error follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4279)()

pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:8543)()

TypeError: an integer is required



C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4150                     if reduce is None:
   4151                         reduce = True
-> 4152                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
   4153             else:
   4154                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4246             try:
   4247                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4248                     results[i] = func(v)
   4249                     keys.append(v.name)
   4250             except Exception as e:

    <ipython-input-13-92e1d7684747> in <lambda>(y)
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-92e1d7684747> in <module>()
     11 df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[0])
     12 
---> 13 df['sumall'] = df.apply(lambda y:  df[df['ENDDATE'] < y['STARTDATE'] ].PROFIT.sum())
     14 df['sumco'] = df.apply(lambda y:  df[(df['ENDDATE'] < y['STARTDATE'] )& (df.co==y.co)].PROFIT.sum())

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    601         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    602         try:
--> 603             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    604 
    605             if not is_scalar(result):

    C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2167         try:
   2168             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2169                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2170         except KeyError as e1:
   2171             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3557)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3240)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4363)()

KeyError: ('STARTDATE', 'occurred at index CO')
```

Answer (score 1):

My take. Certainly there are better ways.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

text = """CO         SECTOR    PROFIT   STARTMVYEAR TOTALPROFIT REPORTDATE
IBM         TECHNOLOGY  -500    2500        500         2017-01-01
APPLE       TECHNOLOGY   800    4000        300         2017-01-02
GM          INDUSTRIAL   250    1000          0         2017-02-01
IBM    INDUSTRIAL   600    3000        100         2017-03-01
IBM    INDUSTRIAL   600    35000        100         2017-03-02"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[0]).sort_values(by="REPORTDATE")
df['sumall'] = df.PROFIT.cumsum()-df['PROFIT']
df['sumco']=df.groupby('CO')['PROFIT'].cumsum()
df['sumco']= np.where(df['sumco'] ==df['PROFIT'], 0, df['sumco'] )
print(df[['CO','REPORTDATE' ,'PROFIT', 'sumall','sumco']])
```

Output

```
      CO  REPORTDATE  PROFIT  sumall  sumco
0    IBM  2017-01-01    -500       0      0
1  APPLE  2017-01-02     800    -500      0
2     GM  2017-02-01     250     300      0
3    IBM  2017-03-01     600     550    100
4    IBM  2017-03-02     600    1150    700
```

Comment: That is really clever, thank you.  It unfortunately leaves me incomplete because off the concept of end dates that I should have  articulated in the original question.  Would you please take another look?  thx

Comment: This is as close as I can get..  df['sumall'] = df['STARTDATE'].apply(lambda y:  df[df['ENDDATE'] < y ].PROFIT.sum())

Comment: I have tried to come up with something, but this last requirement seems a little too complicated to solve using the tools I know.
The requirement is that for the calculation of sumco I should ignore the rows of the same company whose enddate is betwen the startdate and the endate of the row I am processing. It is not as simple as ignoring rows whose startdate is greater than the max enddate of the rows in the same group, because I have not to take into account the end date of the row I am processing.

Comment: Not exactly.. maybe I worded it poorly.. the requirement is that we sum all of the profits of the rows where the end date is less than the start date of the row we are analyzing.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: My approach now would be to divide the dataframe into two different dataframes, ones for calculating sumall, and one for calculating sumco. In the second dataframe I would mark as 'don't add' rows whose start date falls between the startdate and enddate of other period. Then I would proceed to group by company, filtering out the rows I have marked as 'to ignore', and do a cumulative sum on the groups. It sounds convoluted, totally unelegant and panda-unlike, so for now I will leave it to somebody else to try and find a solution fulfilling your last requirement.

Comment: My gut feeling is that panda is not the right tool for this kind of problem, but it might be that I don't know it well enough.

Comment: Very much appreciate your efforts.  Thank you